# Delphi 7 and Indy 9.0 Error Connecting SSL

Tags: delphi, ssl

I'm using `TIdHTTP` component to execute `GET` command, resulting in above error message:

```
Request.ContentType := 'text/html';
Request.CustomHeader.Values['Authorization'] := 'Basic '+ TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeString(SPIAKey)+':'TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeString(SAPISecret);
```

TIdSSLIOHHandlerSocket

Method - sslvSSLv2

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: Could you expand on this part of the question?
TIdSSLIOHHandlerSocket
Method - sslvSSLv2

Comment: I'm not an Indy guy, but what you've posted doesn't suggest any use of SSL at all: `http` is normally non-secure, and the auth methods are as well. A bit more code perhaps?

Comment: Indy 9 is ancient now and laks support for newer encryption methods. You need to update towards [Indy 10](http://www.indyproject.org/)

Answer (score 5):

*NOBODY* uses SSL v2.0 or SSL v3.0 anymore, as they are no longer secure. You need to use TLS v1.0 *at a minimum* <sup>1</sup>. Indy 9's `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocket` component supports up to TLS v1.0 *max*. Set the `SSLOptions.Method` property to `sslvTLSv1` for that.

<sup>1: be aware that websites have slowly been dropping support for TLS v1.0, and major webbrowser vendors are dropping support for TLS v1.0 and v1.1 later this year.</sup>

To use TLS v1.1 and higher, you need to upgrade to Indy 10, where `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocket` has been renamed to `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL`, and its `SSLOptions.Method` property has been deprecated in favor of a new `SSLOptions.SSLVersions` property, which will allow you to enable TLS v1.0, v1.1, and v1.2 at the same time.

---

On a side note, you do not need to use the `TIdHTTP.Request.CustomHeader` property to use `Basic` authentication.  `TIdHTTP` has built-in support for `Basic`.  Simply set the `TIdHTTP.Request.BasicAuthentication` property to True and then use the `TIdHTTP.Request.Username` and `TIdHTTP.Request.Password` properties:

```pascal
Request.ContentType := 'text/html';
Request.BasicAuthentication := True;
Request.Username := SPIAKey;
Request.Password := SAPISecret;
```

This works in both Indy 9 and 10.